# Google app engine - login with Google, Facebook

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth

I would like the users of my application, hosted in Google app engine, login the same way I do in StackExchange, using my Google account or Facebook account.

I have some questions on this:

1. I would like to see some tutorials on basic login only
2. I would like to see some tutorial(s) on social login (Google, Facebook, etc.. )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [Federated login](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html) API provided by Google to help users connect using Open ID providers (like Google, Windows Live, Yahoo, etc.).

Check out these links:

- [Using Federated Authentication via
  OpenID in Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html)
- [A Simple OpenID Login Example on
  Appengine](http://blog.mudy.info/2010/10/a-simple-openid-login-example/)

Comment: Doesn't help in the least with Facebook, unfortunately.

Comment: Indeed, no Facebook.  But I think he wanted more the idea of being able to choose between services like Facebook and Google than necessarily Facebook and Google.
It would be nice to have Facebook though, I agree. But between the convenience of using App Engine's "free" Users API and starting from scratch to accomodate Facebook, for most apps the choice seems obvious.

Comment: This information is now out of date. Google discontinued the Federated login

Answer (score 3):

A login system is rather straightforward. Basically it is something like this:

User wants to access something that is restricted and needs a valid Account.

You check if he is logged in.

If not, you prompt the user to either create an account, or login.

If he has an account he will enter his username/password combination (preferably over SSL). You then check if the combination is valid and set his state to logged in. The best way to do this would be a cookie plus a session variable, but it depends on what you want to use.

If the user has not an account you can give him the choice to create one. Here you let him fill out everything you need, Name, username, password et cetera. And be sure to send it all over SSL again.

From there he then should be able to login successfully.

If you want some code this seems to be complete: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Basic-Login-Script-in-PHP

For facebook, it is a bit different as Facebook requires the user to be logged in and prompts on it's own if he is not. To see how to use the Facebook API you can go here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

The Authentication part is the one you should look at.

Answer (score 0):

A good example for facebook authentication is [runwithfriends](https://github.com/facebook/runwithfriends).

The source is available and I suggest you take it and learn and your facebook authentication will work.

Answer (score 0):

Because google has blocked this feature since 2019, there is no way to fix it.
I can't find any way to fix this error either. I chose the solution of redirecting google login link to default browser.
My new solution is:

Insert this code inside

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { .... code...}
```

**Code:**

```
//Redirecting google login link:
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && (url.startsWith(("https://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?loginSocial=google")) )) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity (
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```